# Naming convention to distinguish in-place mutation/creation function

Tags: naming-conventions, in-place

When I wrote some general programming utility code, I found that it's good to have both inplace mutator and new object creator member function for one functionality.

For example, some class which represents path in file system may have "normalize" functionality. Path object may mutates itself into normalized one, or returns new normalized path object.

```
class path {
  ...

  void normalize_itself()
  path get_new_normalized_path()

  ...
}
```

I've tried some convention for this one, but most of them are not satisfiable.

1. 'normalize!' for inplace function like ruby - good, but most other languages don't support special character to be included in identifier.
2. 'normalize_ip' for inplace function - since most of my function usages are inplace, I think it's too ugly.
3. 'get_normalized' for non-inplace function - acceptable, but can be confused with other simple getter function for member.
4. 'normalized' for non-inplace function - sometime not uniform, and easily confused with its inplace counter part.
5. write non-inplace function as free function - lack of intellisense assistance of IDE, sometime visibility issues.

I'd like to find some good/practical convention to distinguish two function.

Answer (score 0):

I think `normalize` for your mutator and `grab_normalized` for your object creator would work.